# Selenium Chromedriver call to logout page not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, behat

I want to write an automated test with Selenium using Chromedriver and Behat.

This scenario in question should go to a page, register a user, logout and register another user.

Now the problem is, on the website in question, after registration you get an annoying overlay, so that the logout button is not reachable anymore. I can either make the test fill out the overlay and complete it properly, which will take much more effort, or try to logout some other way.

My idea was to simply go to the domain again with /?event=logout added which normally works to log out the current user. However when I do this in the automation it fails, apparently because of a bad http response code.

Is it not possible to use a url like this with Selenium? Anyone have an idea?

Comment: How do you use the URL with selenium? When you run manually it works as I understand - do you use the same Chrome profile with ChromeDriver?

Comment: The problem now seems to be that I call www.website.com/?event=logout, but the test opens www.website.com/?event=logout/, with the slash at the end, which leads to an error page. I am not sure if I can avoid this somehow.

Comment: Can you add an error for the logout?

Answer (score 0):

Some options would be:

1. Navigate to URL to logout and try to hide the modal via jQuery/javascript
2. After registration navigate to homepage and see if the modal is there and if you can logout as you should
3. Clear session and navigate to the page you need

Pick one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Selenium using a site that makes GET requests. So you can go to URL http://requestmaker.com/, fill the www.website.com in the Request URL, and 'event=logout' in the Request data, then click "Submit".

It's a bit hacky, so I would prefer using a GET request directly in the code, depending on your programming language... Something like so:

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/